# postagem de imagem

Tags: php

faz tempo que estou tentando postar uma imagem junto com um texto e nao consigo. quando clico no botao cadastrar, só cadastra o texto, mas a imagem nao cadastra. veja meu codigo:

Arquivo insere:

```
<?php
    $conect = mysql_connect('mysql.hostinger.com.br','u728177807_post','cristaleye');
    $db = mysql_select_db('u728177807_post');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Documento sem t&iacute;tulo</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Título: <input type="text" name="titulo"/><br /><br />

<input type="file" name="imagem" value="imagem" />
Texto: <textarea name="texto" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="acao" value="cad" />


<input type="submit" value="cadastrar" />


</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'cad'){
        $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
        $imagem = $_POST['imagem'];
        $texto = $_POST['texto'];







        if(empty($titulo) || empty($texto)){
                echo '<script>alert("Preencha todos os campos!");</script>';
        }else{
            $inserir = mysql_query("INSERT INTO postagens (titulo, imagem, texto) VALUES ('$titulo','$imagem','$texto')");
            echo '<script>alert("Cadastrado com sucesso!");</script>';
        }}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

arquivo posts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Documento sem t&iacute;tulo</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="corpo">
<?php
    $seleciona = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM postagens ORDER BY id DESC");
    $conta = mysql_num_rows($seleciona);

    if($conta <= 0){
        echo "Não há nenhum dado no banco!";
    }else{
        while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($seleciona)){
            $titulo = $ln['titulo'];
            $conteudo = $ln['texto'];
            $imagem = $ln['imagem'];
?>
<div id="post">
<h1><?php echo $titulo; ?></h1>
<img src="images/<?php echo $imagem; ?>" width="450" height="280" border="0" />
<p><?php echo $conteudo; ?></p>
</div><br /><br />
<?php }} ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

digito o texto e coloco a imagem no insere.php mas so cadastra o texto no posts.php

Comment: Comece lendo a documentação [Upload de arquivos com o método POST](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php) e busque aqui no site por "php upload imagem" que vrá várias perguntas relacionadas a isso. Provavelmente assim você já conseguirá fazer algo a mais.

Answer (score 0):

O array que permite manipular arquivos é $_FILES, por isso a imagem não vai.. de uma procurada no manual, o método é um pouco diferente mas é fácil